# add a javascript function to navigation bar append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, append

please take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/g5Fbr/2/

In the **HTML screen**, we have **2 codes**:

**First part of the html code -** it declares the js source and calls a js function. This results in the "sacola de compras" link in the Result screen.
This is the code:

```
<div> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://app.ecwid.com/script.js?4549118"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> xMinicart("style=","layout=Mini"); </script> 
</div>
```

**Second part of the html code -** it creates a navigation bar which has two links ("page1" and "page2") as you can see in the Result screen.

I want the first link ("sacola de compras") to appear below "page2" **as part of the navigation bar**. Since I cannot edit the navigation bar code, I am using the **Javascript screen to try to append the js function**. You can see what I'm trying to do in the **Javascript screen**.

Please do help!

Thanks!

**edit 1:**

So you can see what I'm trying to do: what I need is the following http://jsfiddle.net/u3NKD/5/ The results are two links. However, the second link (the one which says "sacola de compras), must be done with append(), not html. That's what I'm trying to do

Comment: I'm a bit confused - I modified your code with a simple .append to .cf and was able to get a working anchor. But what do you want to happen when the third link is clicked?

Comment: thanks for helping! So you can see what I'm trying to do: what I need is the following http://jsfiddle.net/u3NKD/5/ The results are two links. However, the second link (the one which says "sacola de compras), must be done with append(), not html. That's what I'm trying to do